# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getInstallSourceInfo

Tags: android

In my Android app I have the following code:

```
String market_name = context.getPackageManager().getInstallSourceInfo(context.getPackageName()).getInstallingPackageName();
```

that crashes on devices with API level < 30 with

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getInstallSourceInfo
```

Should I use [getInstallerPackageName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstallerPackageName(java.lang.String)) instead if my app API level is 23+ (it runs on devices with API level 23+)?

Assume [getInstallerPackageName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstallerPackageName(java.lang.String)) will be removed in Android 15, what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getInstallSourceInfo` method for API 30+ and `getInstallerPackageName` method for API below 30. Something like this :

```
 public String getInstallSource() {
    String installSource = "";
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            installSource = context.getPackageManager().getInstallSourceInfo(packageInfo.packageName).getInstallingPackageName();
        } else {
            installSource = context.getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName(packageInfo.packageName);
        }
        if (installSource == null) installSource = "Unknown" 
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException | IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        installSource = "Unknown";
    }

    return installSource;
}
```